# Replace value in an array by its index in a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In a given array I want to replace the values by the index of this value in an other array (which doesn't contain duplicates). Here is a simple example of I'm trying to do:

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

a = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [0, 1, 3]])
chg = np.array([3, 0, 2, 1])

b = deepcopy(a)
for new, old  in enumerate(chg):
   b[a == old] = new

print b
# [[1 3 2] [2 3 0] [1 3 0]]
```

But I need to do that on large arrays so having an explicit loop is not acceptable in terms of execution time.

I can't figure out how to do that using fancy numpy functions...

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: @JoranBeasley:  To me it looks like he's taking the values in `a`, finding their index in `chg` and creating a new structure `b` that holds the indexes.

Comment: Also don't understand this. I don't think the code is doing what the OP expects. By the way you can just do `b = a.copy()`...

Comment: @YXD:  Regarding using `a.copy`, I believe modifying the subarrays would modify the original array without `deepcopy`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski ok I see it now

Comment: @StevenRumbalski it doesn't: `a = np.arange(5); b = a.copy(); b[0] = 7; print(a)` - a is not modified

Comment: @YXD:  I stand corrected.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Steven Rumbalski is right, that is what I am trying to do. (thanks for the copy tip, I also thought I needed a deepcopy)

Comment: @thomleo: are you looking for a solution only in NumPy, or can you use (for example) pandas?

Comment: @ajcr I would prefer numpy but if you have a easy way in panda (or else) that could be a start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`take` is your friend.

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [0, 1, 3]])
chg = np.array([3, 0, 2, 1])
inverse_chg=chg.take(chg)
print(inverse_chg.take(a))
```

gives :

```
[[1 3 2]
 [2 3 0]
 [1 3 0]]
```

or more directly with fancy indexing: `chg[chg][a]`, but `inverse_chg.take(a)` is three times faster.

Comment: Cool use of `take` (+1) but this might break if `chg = np.array([4, 0, 2, 1])`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

This type of replacement operation can be tricky to do in full generality with NumPy, although you could use `searchsorted`:

```
>>> s = np.argsort(chg)
>>> s[np.searchsorted(chg, a.ravel(), sorter=s).reshape(a.shape)]
array([[1, 3, 2],
       [2, 3, 0],
       [1, 3, 0]])
```

(Note: `searchsorted` doesn't just replace exact matches, so be careful if you have values in `a` that aren't in `chg`...)

pandas has a variety of tools which can make these operations on NumPy arrays much easier and potentially a lot quicker / more memory efficient for larger arrays. For this specific problem, `pd.match` could be used:

```
>>> pd.match(a.ravel(), chg).reshape(a.shape)
array([[1, 3, 2],
       [2, 3, 0],
       [1, 3, 0]])
```

This function also allows you to specify what value should be filled if a value is missing from `chg`.

Comment: Good to see `searchsorted`! Guess not for cases like `chg = np.array([4, 0, 2, 1])`? But since OP accepted .`take` that assumes the same, maybe this would work for OP too.

Comment: @Divakar: thanks - this should actually work for the cases like `chg = np.array([4, 0, 2, 1])`, although I should probably caveat the answer by saying that `searchsorted` doesn't look for *exact* matches, so it might replace values in `a` that don't exist in `chg`.

Comment: Yeah well, if `chg` has all the values that exist in `a`, this might just be the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `chg` to a 3D array by adding two new axes at the end of it and then perform the matching comparison with `a`, which would bring in [`NumPy's broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to give us a 3D mask. Next up, get the `argmax` on the mask along the first axis to simulate `"b[a == old] = new"`. Finally, replace the ones that had no matches along that axis with the corresponding values in `a`. The implementation would look something like this -

```
mask = a == chg[:,None,None]
out = mask.argmax(0)
invalid_pos = ~mask.max(0)
out[invalid_pos] = a[invalid_pos]
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this out:

```
a = np.array([3,4,1,2,0])
b = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4]])

c = b[a]
print(c)
```

It gives me back:

```
[[0 3]
 [0 4]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [0 0]]
```

If you're working with numpy arrays you could do this.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I'm trying to do... cause this is just a reordering of your array that you are doing.